# django 1.1 permission question in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-permissions

I have an app that makes user of filtering certain things for users with different permissions.

Django 1.1 does for some reason not seem to recognize these.

I have a group called `corporate` and `permissions` are granted as needed.

now in my template I am render the following.

> {% if perms.corporate %}
>       ...show the following
>   {% else %}
>       ... show something else
>   {% endif %}

why is this not rendering the info I want?

Comment: have you tried what {{ perms.corporate }} returns?

Comment: Depends on what the value of `perms` is in the form context.  The form -- by itself -- isn't enough information to answer the question.  The context created by the view function is **essential** information.  Please UPDATE the question with the context created by the view function for the form.  Please do not comment.  Please UPDATE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`perms.corporate` proxies to `User.has_module_perms('corporate')`. So you need to have a module (or app) labeled `corporate`. You say your current corporate is a group, so this probably won't work.

Comment: thanks, yeah I was trying to go the wrong route.

So is there anyway that you can call the `Group` instead of the permissions? or is this the wrong route I might be taking?